# ssh with -oBatchMode=yes fails; without succeeds - no password requested

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm using -oBatchMode=yes to suppress the interactive password, in case the keys are misconfigured.

I've used 'diff' to compare the debug output, and there's no change until 'Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279', where the next line is either 'Authentication succeeded' or trying more private keys.

From the script and from the command-line, running without batch mode results in a successful login:

```
$ ssh -v  qa@192.168.19.81  uptime
.
.
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.19.81' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/tim/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
--- things change from here
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.19.81 ([192.168.19.81]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug1: Sending command: uptime
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
13:24  up 3 days,  3:04, 2 users, load averages: 1.76 1.62 1.61
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2768, received 3080 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 129171.8, received 143731.6
debug1: Exit status 0
```

But the same fails with -oBatchMode=yes:

```
$ ssh -v -oBatchMode=yes  qa@192.168.19.81  uptime
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
.
.
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/tim/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
--- things change from here
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/tim/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/tim/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/tim/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
$
```

Remote machine:
Darwin qa-ffc-mbp-2.lnd 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

My machine:
Darwin TimBs-MacBook-Pro-3483.local 16.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0: Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

---

update: I copied the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub from an account that doesn't have this problem, and it started working. But my id_rsa.pub is correctly listed in the target machine's authorized_keys. I even regenerated my public key from the private one, in case it had become corrupted. No dice. I'm reluctant to change my key for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding these lines to your ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host *
UseKeychain yes
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I worked around the issue by other means. If the problem happens again, I'll try it though!

Answer (score 0):

Seems Apple's integration of keychain is disabled by `BatchMode=yes`

If I `eval $(ssh-agent)` and `ssh-add` my identity, everything works.

The reason the other account's key worked was because it had an empty passphrase.